# InvalidPathException when using type name as alias

Tags: nhibernate, hql, alias

I've a problem with following Hql Query:

```
FROM PhysikalischesObjekt physikalischesObjekt LEFT OUTER JOIN FETCH physikalischesobjekt.AktuelleInstallation installation
```

As you see - i'm using aliases that named like the entity (just with lower letter at the first position).

If im execute this query to Nhibernate, i get a InvalidPathException:

```
NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.InvalidPathException : Invalid path: 'physikalischesobjekt.AktuelleInstallation' [FROM PhysikalischesObjekt physikalischesObjekt LEFT OUTER JOIN FETCH physikalischesobjekt.AktuelleInstallation installation ]
```

Stacktrace:

```
>   NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Util.LiteralProcessor.LookupConstant(NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.DotNode node) Zeile 81   C#
NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.DotNode.Resolve(bool generateJoin, bool implicitJoin, string classAlias, NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.IASTNode parent) Zeile 208  C#
NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.FromReferenceNode.Resolve(bool generateJoin, bool implicitJoin, string classAlias) Zeile 58    C#
NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.CreateFromJoinElement(NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.IASTNode path, NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.IASTNode alias, int joinType, NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.IASTNode fetchNode, NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.IASTNode propertyFetch, NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.IASTNode with) Zeile 681  C#
NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.joinElement() Zeile 3955 + 0x3c Bytes  C#
NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.fromElement() Zeile 3617 + 0xc Bytes   C#
NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.fromElementList() Zeile 3391 + 0xc Bytes   C#
NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.fromClause() Zeile 3308 + 0xc Bytes    C#
NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.unionedQuery() Zeile 1645 + 0xc Bytes  C#
NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.query() Zeile 1510 + 0xc Bytes C#
NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.selectStatement() Zeile 536 + 0xc Bytes    C#
NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.statement() Zeile 435 + 0xc Bytes  C#
NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlTranslator.Translate() Zeile 590 + 0x1b Bytes C#
NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.Analyze(string collectionRole) Zeile 449 + 0x12 Bytes   C#
NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.DoCompile(System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,string> replacements, bool shallow, string collectionRole) Zeile 354 + 0x13 Bytes   C#
NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.Compile(System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,string> replacements, bool shallow) Zeile 72  C#
NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.IASTNode ast, string queryIdentifier, string collectionRole, bool shallow, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,NHibernate.IFilter> filters, NHibernate.Engine.ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) Zeile 43 + 0xa3 Bytes    Unknown
NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(string queryString, string collectionRole, bool shallow, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,NHibernate.IFilter> filters, NHibernate.Engine.ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) Zeile 21 + 0x3a Bytes    C#
NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLStringQueryPlan.CreateTranslators(string hql, string collectionRole, bool shallow, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,NHibernate.IFilter> enabledFilters, NHibernate.Engine.ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) Zeile 24 + 0x99 Bytes  C#
NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLStringQueryPlan.HQLStringQueryPlan(string hql, string collectionRole, bool shallow, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,NHibernate.IFilter> enabledFilters, NHibernate.Engine.ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) Zeile 16 + 0x3e Bytes C#
NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLStringQueryPlan.HQLStringQueryPlan(string hql, bool shallow, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,NHibernate.IFilter> enabledFilters, NHibernate.Engine.ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) Zeile 14 C#
NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(string queryString, bool shallow, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,NHibernate.IFilter> enabledFilters) Zeile 61 + 0x5b Bytes C#
NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(string query, bool shallow) Zeile 304 + 0x87 Bytes   C#
NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(string queryString) Zeile 283 + 0x3b Bytes   C#
```

Is there a problem using alias like this in Hql? Is there a Syntax that disallows to use the same alias name as the entity name? It seems that Nhibernate tries find a persister for the alias name which doesn't work, obviously.

Comment: I suspect you have answered your own question! Trying to work out why you would want an alias the same length as the class? Surely not using an alias in your case would be better!

Comment: I haven't found any documentation about a alias name convention. The aliases are genrated automatically by an HQL builde we made. Is there a documentation about this convention?

Comment: Interesting looking at the docs you can use an alias if it is different by case. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-from Looks like your error is elsewhere. Wish you luck

Comment: If the alias name is "x" for example it works fine. We have tried the following statement successfully:

    "FROM PhysikalischesObjekt x LEFT OUTER JOIN FETCH x.AktuelleInstallation y".

So the alias name is the cause of the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alias you used are not the same: "physikalischesObjekt" and "physikalisachesobjekt".